# Why can't i install PostgreSQL on Windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64kKC.png)

Hello, i tried to run .exe file PostgreSQL 14.2 version (download from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) and get this error like in the picture. I also tried to run a lot of versions (started from 10.2 and end 14.2) but getting this error. What should i do?

Comment: Maybe something is corrupting your downloads? For `postgresql-14.2-1-windows-x64.exe` I get a CRC32 of `1B70EBCE`.

Answer (score 0):

I was in trouble with the same phenomenon as you. But after installing windows update KB5011487 yesterday, the problem went away.  Build No. of windows10(pro)  is 19043.1586.